# Is it reliable to rely on external authentication providers in the long run?

Tags: authentication, social-login

We use Google+, Facebook and Twitter oauth2 APIs for our membership infrastructure, because our content policy strictly prohibits standalone ownership of content by user (means that there is no password to login, only way to login is social authentication and If any legal issue happens, user information can only be asked to these three providers).

However, there is one concern. Although these three companies don't seem to disappear in the future, but still is it reliable for long term application?

If this is a common problem, what is the most common action taken by the team?

Answer (score 2):

If you're a small or medium team, then it's certainly worth it in the long run. It's much easier to store credentials in third-party specialized servers, and (most important for me) if something goes wrong and someone learns what they shouldn't know, only the third party is to blame (the services won't shut down any time soon).